# Type {} is not assignable to a custom type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I defined the following two custom types. However, the typescript compiler continued to raise errors.

```
type StatusProps = {
  [key: string]: React.JSX.Element;
}

type ToggleStatus<T extends StatusProps> = {
  [key in Extract<T, string> as `toggle${Capitalize<key>}`]: () => void;
}


const toggleStatus: ToggleStatus<T> = {} // TS2322: Type {} is not assignable to type ToggleStatus<T> 
Object.keys(props.status).forEach((key) => {
  const capitalizeKey = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)
  toggleStatus[`toggle${capitalizeKey}`] = () => {} // TS7053: Element implicitly has an  any  type because expression of type `toggle${string}` can't be used to index type  ToggleStatus<T> 
})
```

I tried to change the type definition as:

```
export type ToggleStatus<T extends StatusProps> = {
  [key: string]: () => void;
}
```

but the generic type won't work well in this way.

Comment: You should either use `Object.fromEntries` to create the object or use a type assertion instead of a type annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try following changes . . .

```
type StatusProps = {
  [key: string]: React.JSX.Element;
};

type ToggleStatus<T extends StatusProps> = {
  [key in keyof T as `toggle${Capitalize<string & key>}`]: () => void;
};

const toggleStatus = {} as ToggleStatus<StatusProps>; // Type assertion

Object.keys(props.status).forEach((key) => {
  const capitalizeKey = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
  toggleStatus[`toggle${capitalizeKey}`] = () => {};
});
```

In this code, I used the as keyword to explicitly assert the type of toggleStatus as ToggleStatus. This informs TypeScript that you are sure toggleStatus conforms to the expected type.